# How do I unlock new boost rush levels?

Tags: new-super-mario-bros-u

How do I unlock the other boost rush levels as there are yellow boxes where I assume that other level packs should go. Anyone know how to get them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to progress in the main games levels. When you complete enough of them a pack will be unlocked.

If you have completed all the levels, then you have everything.

They were going to do Boost Rush DLC, but they decided to do 82 Luigi-themed levels instead (New Super Luigi U) which cannot be played in Boost Rush mode.

Comment: I forgot I ever asked this question xD Thanks for telling me although now I know :) I didn't know about the Luigi bit though so bonus marks for that! I still can't beat the last boost rush pack though :P